# Rails5 ActionCable Chat with Conversations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

According to DHHs Rails5 ActionCable chat example I'm going to create a further example with conversations and many messages in there:

```
rails g model conversation 

class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
end

rails g model message content:text conversation:references
```

view/conversations/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Conversation</h1>

<div id="messages">
  <%= render @messages %>
</div>

<form>
  <label>Say something:</label><br>
  <input type="text" data-behavior="conversation_speaker">
</form>
```

view/messages/_message.html.erb

```
<div class="message">
  <p><%= message.content %></p>
</div>
```

My questions is how to write a channel logic that every message related to its conversation gets written to the database:

First I recorded a conversation and a message on the console

```
Conversation.create
Message.create(conversation_id: '1', content: 'hello')
```

afterwards I created a Job

```
rails g job MessageBroadcast

class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  render_message(message)
  def perform(data)
    message = Message.create! content: data
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'conversation_channel', message: render_message(message)
  end

  private
    def render_message(message)
      ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'messages/message',
                                             locals: { message: message })
    end
end
```

and a channel

```
rails g channel conversation speak
```

assets/javascripts/channels/conversation.coffee

```
App.conversation = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ConversationChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    # Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    $('#messages').append data['message']

  speak: ->
    @perform 'speak'

$(document).on 'keypress', '[data-behavior~=conversation_speaker]', (event) ->
  if event.keyCode is 13 # return = send
    App.conversation.speak event.target.value
    event.target.value = ""
    event.preventDefault()
```

If I write:

channels/conversation_channel.rb

```
class ConversationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "conversation_channel"
  end

  def speak
    Message.create! content: data['message']
  end
end
```

I get

```
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2016-04-22 00:22:13 +0200
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-a
live, Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2016-04-22 00:22:13 +0200
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2016-04-22 00:22:13 +0200
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-a
live, Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
ConversationChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
ConversationChannel is streaming from conversation_channel
ConversationChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
ConversationChannel is streaming from conversation_channel
```

looks okay but if I enter some text in the textfield and hit return I get:

```
Could not execute command from {"command"=>"message", 
"identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"ConversationChannel\"}", 
"data"=>"{\"action\":\"speak\"}"}) 
[NameError - undefined local variable or method `data' for #<ConversationChannel:0x00000008ad3100>]: 
C:/Sites/ActionCable/app/channels/conversation_channel.rb:13:
in `speak' | C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_cable/channel/base.rb:253:
in `public_send' | C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_cable/channel/base.rb:253:
in `dispatch_action' | C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_cable/channel/base.rb:163:
in `perform_action' | C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.beta3/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:49:
in `perform_action'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you restarted your server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going from the client side to the server side, you must (first of all) make your `speak` function accepts a `message` parameter AND send that message to the server as a JSON object.

```
speak: (message) ->
  @perform 'speak', message: message
```

Second, you have to define the parameters received by `speak` function at channels/conversation_channel.rb. Thus you must redefine it as:

```
def speak(data)
  Message.create! content: data['message']
end
```

Now your `speak` method is receiving a `data` parameter, which is a JSON with a `message` property which contains the message sent to the server. It's being recorded to the database, but there is no answer to those subscribed to the channel.

Thus we must notify them redefining the method above as:

```
def speak(data)
  Message.create! content: data['message']
  ActionCable.server.broadcast 'conversation_channel', message: render_message(message)
end

private

def render_message(message)
  ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'messages/message',
                                         locals: { message: message })
end
```

Now it's supposed to work. What you'll do in background is up to you ;)

Comment: I've added the data params and restarted the server. Thanks, you helped me out.

Comment: Finally a working example! I believe you would want to replace the first line in speak to: `message = Message.create! content: data['message'], conversation_id: '1'`

Comment: Hi @Cristiano
I'm having problem that my `speak: (message) ->
  @perform 'speak', message: message` is returning false, so it's never going to server side as I put pry there and server console is not being stopped, So it makes sure that I'm not being able to go from client to server.